# How to search code in directory from within VSCode extension?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm attempting to write a VSCode extension and I need to search all of the code in the directory for certain keywords. Basically, I want to simulate the results of running a search in the sidebar (`ctrl+shift+f`) and store that in a variable.
I've looked through the docs multiple times but maybe I overlooked something?
Any help would be majorly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
jmoore914

EDIT:

Thought I found the answer with the following:
Hmm, thought I had the solution but apparently not.

I tried using the following:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles', {
            query: wordText,
            triggerSearch: true,
            matchWholeWord: true,
            isCaseSensitive: true,
        });
```

This triggers a search in the sidebar but I would rather not do that and instead just store the search results into a variable. Any ideas?
Thanks!